# Unable to choose between minor and major versions when checking in .mpp files

Tags: 2010

Add a Microsoft Project 2010 .mpp file to a SharePoint 2010 document library.
'Create major and minor (draft) versions' is turned on in the library.
Click on the .mpp file from within the doc library.
Choose Check out and Edit in the Open Document box.
File opens in Project.
Edit the Project file.
Close Project using the X.
Check In box displays giving four options (Save changes and check in, Save Changes only, Discard changes and undo check out, Discard changes only).
Choose Save changes and check in.
.mpp is checked in.
The file is automatically checked in as a minor version. 
To make it a major version I need to use the dropdown menu for the .mpp file and select to Publish a Major Version.

Question:
Is this the way SharePoint manages .mpp files? i.e. it is not possible to get the option to choose between minor and major version when checking in the .mpp file following the steps above?

Comment: Which version of ms project do you have installed? I havent ms project, but in Office like Word and so on there is under the ribbon the option "Check-In" and there I can decide if I want a major or a minor version.